# Spring Controller Unit Test throws NestedServletException

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit4, mockmvc

I have a Spring controller that throws an error when there is no data. I want to test the exception, which is custom `NoDataFoundException` , but it always throws `org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException`

The unit test error message is: `java.lang.Exception: Unexpected exception, expected<com.project.NoDataFoundException> but was<org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException>`

**Controller Unit Test**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MockConfiguration.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ModelControllerTest{

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Inject
    private ModelController controller;

    @Inject
    private ResponseBuilder responseBuilder;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
    }

    @Test(expected = NoDataFoundException.class)
    public void findAllModels_invalidRequest_throwNoDataFound() throws Exception {
        when(responseBuilder.findAll(any())).thenReturn(null);
        mockMvc
        .perform(get("/models"))
            .andExpect(status().isInternalServerError());
    }

}
```

**Controller**

```
@GetMapping("/models")
public ResponseEntity<List<Model>> findAllModels() {
    //Some Logic 
    dataExistenceCheck(response);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}

private <T> void dataExistenceCheck(T target) {
    if (target == null || (target instanceof Collection && ((Collection<?>) target).isEmpty())) {
        throw new NoDataFoundException();
    }
}
```

**NoDataFoundException Class**

```
public class NoDataFoundException extends RuntimeException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 140836818081224458L;

    public NoDataFoundException() {
        super();
    }

    public NoDataFoundException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

}
```

**Finding**

I debugged the codes and traced until the `org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet` class. Yes, I expected the `NoDataFoundException` but there it throws `NesteServletException`.

How can I solve that? What did I do wrong?

[image]

---

**Edited Question**

I have `@ControllerAdvice` and handle `NoDataFoundException`, but it hits `NestedServletException` before reaching here.

```
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
@ExceptionHandler(NoDataFoundException.class)
public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> noDataFoundExceptionHandler(NoDataFoundException exception) {
    LOGGER.debug("No data found exception [{}].", exception);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new ErrorResponse("not found"), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

`NestedServletException` is a wrapper/adapter that adopt all exceptions to `javax.servlet.ServletException`. It is part of java servlet API.

You can solve it in following ways:

1) Catch `NestedServletException` and rethrow cause:

```
try {
    mockMvc
    .perform(get("/models"))
        .andExpect(status().isInternalServerError());
} catch (NestedServletException e) {
    throw e.getCause();
}
```

2) Use `org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThatThrownBy`

```
@Test
public void findAllModels_invalidRequest_throwNoDataFound() throws Throwable {
    Assertions.assertThatThrownBy(() ->
            mockMvc.perform(get("/models")).andExpect(status().isInternalServerError()))
            .hasCause(new NoDataFoundException(null));
}
```

3) In your controller or global exception handler add `@ExceptionHandler(NoDataFoundException.class)` and translate it into valid Http code and response body.

4) Extends `NoDataFoundException` from `ServletException`

Comment: thanks, i actually had controller advice that handles `@ExceptionHandler(NoDataFoundException.class)`, but the error not even reaching there, see my edited question.

Comment: Your exception handler works perfectly. I have committed test into github. You can clone it by : https://github.com/ivan333m/mock.git

Have a look at https://github.com/ivan333m/mock/blob/master/demo/src/test/java/com/example/demo/rest/ModelControllerTest.java

I think exception handler is the best solution.

Comment: As you can see in my test I assert http code `status().is4xxClientError()` and content `.andExpect(content().string("{\"error\":\"not found\"}"));`. It is the evidence that your exception handler works fine. :)

Comment: @hades did you find a solution to this? Indeed it seems that controller exception handler is not triggered when an exception is thrown.

Comment: I am facing same issue but interestingly this issue occurs on Wildfly 17. Rest of the application servers behave as expected and the custom exception handler is getting invoked as expected. 
Why is only Widlfly server behaves in this odd way?

Answer (score 1):

I see two options for you:

1. Make your `NoDataFoundException` extending `ServletException`. I am not sure if it would fit you, because it will make your exception checked.
2. Use another approach to check what exception was thrown, like [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44900646/how-to-prevent-nestedservletexception-when-testing-spring-endpoints)

Actually, it's better to always write such sort of tests according to the second option, because according to [Servlet Specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44900646/how-to-prevent-nestedservletexception-when-testing-spring-endpoints):

> A servlet or filter may throw the following exceptions during
>   processing of a request:
>
> 1. runtime exceptions or errors
> 2. ServletExceptions or subclasses thereof
> 3. IOExceptions or subclasses thereof

PS: If you are interested in reasons of why Spring handles exceptions in such way, I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58101351/why-do-spring-wrap-runtimeexception-in-nestedservletexception)