# Why does Spring wrap RuntimeException in NestedServletException when handle endpoint exception?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

According to [Servlet Specification](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=340):

> A servlet or filter may throw the following exceptions during
>   processing of a request:
>
> 1. runtime exceptions or errors
> 2. ServletExceptions or subclasses thereof
> 3. IOExceptions or subclasses thereof

If we look at `org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet#processRequest`, we'll see that Spring throws `ServletException` and `IOException`, but wraps others including `RuntimeExceptions`:

```
try {
    doService(request, response);
} catch (ServletException | IOException ex) {
    failureCause = ex;
    throw ex;
} catch (Throwable ex) {
    failureCause = ex;
    throw new NestedServletException("Request processing failed", ex);
}
```

Why doesn't Spring handle `RuntimeException` like `IOException`?

**UPD**: In other words, what wrong would happen if they handle exceptions this way:

```
try {
    doService(request, response);
} catch (ServletException | IOException | RuntimeException ex) {
    failureCause = ex;
    throw ex;
} catch (Throwable ex) {
    failureCause = ex;
    throw new NestedServletException("Request processing failed", ex);
}
```

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/NestedServletException.html

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, thanks, I've already read this, but I still don't understand why spring do that. For instance, why it doesn't wrap IOException and ServletException then?

Comment: What value would a `NestedServletException` with a root cause of `ServletException` (with no root cause of its own) have over just the `ServletException`? The `IOException` doesn't have the limitation described in the linked javadoc  and so also doesn't need to be wrapped.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, what limitation RuntimeException has if compared to IOException? If you would be kind to explain it in your answer I would be happy to mark it as right answer, because what is written in javadoc about the reasons is convoluted for me.

Comment: By reading the javadoc it seems that ServletException is indeed the one with certain limitations (no root cause or message) yet is still not wrapped. Not sure which limitation were attributed to IOException in previous comments, to me is the same as ServletException being direct descendant of Exception. Finally I believe it to be a design choice, I personally wrap exception together when I want my system to react to a set of exception in the same way. I include runtime exception when I want my system to react gracefully and not simply blow up. Servlet and IO will have specific treatment.

Answer (score 0):

This is required because the protected abstract `doService` method invoked inside `processRequest` can throw any checked or unchecked `Exception`.

```
protected abstract void doService(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception;
```

Now, imagine that you override `doService` like:

```
@Override
protected void doService(Long request, Long response) throws ClassNotFoundException {
// whatever ...
}
```

This would be perfectly legitimate but then `processRequest` will be potentially throwing a `ClassNotFoundException` which you will have to declare as a checked exception. And because `processRequest` is used by `doGet`, `doPost` and the other API methods, these will have to declare `ClassNotFoundException` as well, breaking the specification.

Note that this applies mostly to the case when `doService` is not the implementation provided by `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet`. `doService` in `DispatcherServlet` calls `doDispatch` and `doDispatch` already catches everything but `ServletException` or `IOException`. However, there is still the need of catching the exceptions again because the declaration of `doService` and `doDispatch` do not restrict the list of their checked exceptions to `ServletException` and `IOException`.

**Edit 21/11/2019**:

I do not see any trouble in your alternative exception handling convention. Indeed is closer to the spec interpreted literally.
The implementation is just wrapping everything which is not a ServletException or IOException.
It might be because later a handler is sensitive to the exception type. But this is not the case at least for the [DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.java) used by the [DispatcherServlet](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.java).

I can't see neither any obvious problem which could affect error handling in web.xml with `<error-page><exception-type>...</exception-type></error-page>` or using a `@Component` implementing `ErrorPageRegistrar`.

Comment: Hello, thank you for paying attention to this question. I think you misunderstood it a little, the question is: why they dont handle runtime exceptions as ServletException or IOException, they could do it like `catch (ServletException | IOException | RuntimeException ex)`. Javadoc says that a root cause can be missed, but why it can't be missed if IOException occurred?

Comment: Hi! Because `RuntimeException` is a subclass of `Exception` and thus `(ServletException | IOException | RuntimeException ex)` would not catch every possible exception thrown by `doService` And because it wants to apply a `NestedServletException` wrapper only when actually needed in order to minimize the stack trace length in the logs. In my opinion, it goes too far with `catch (Throwable ex)` because this will catch really bad things like `java.lang.VirtualMachineError` I think it should better do just `catch (Exception ex)`.

Comment: About the root cause, what the spec v3.1 section 9.5 says is : "
If the servlet ... throws a runtime exception or a checked exception of type ServletException or IOException, it should be propagated to the calling servlet. All other exceptions should be wrapped as ServletExceptions and the root cause of the exception set to the original exception, as it should not be propagated". So an `IOException` may or may not have a cause. It is only for the exceptions wrapped with a subclass of `ServletException` for which the cause is mandatory being this cause the original RuntimeException.

Comment: I've updated the post, could you please modify your answer according to that?